# How many non-negative integer solutions to $a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_k\leq n$ with given $n$ and $k$?

Tags: combinatorics

> I want to count the non-negative integer solutions to the following inequality:
>   $$
> a_1+\cdots+a_k\leq n
> $$
>   where $n$ and $k$ are given nonnegative integers.

I tried using stars and bars for each integer less than $n$ ($n-1,n-2,n-3\dots 3,2,1$), but that didn't help since I only got a sigma.

Btw the answer cannot involve a sigma or a ...

Comment: Do you mean $a_1+a_2+...$ ? And if you do mean that then the solution highly depends on what these values are. A generalized answer wouldn't be possible, but one could find an upper bound for certain $n$ and $k$

Comment: Are $a_1, a_2,\dots,a_k$ positive integers? non-negative integers? Or something?

Comment: yeah nonegative

Comment: For $n = 6$ and $k = 2$, are $3 + 2$ and $2 + 3$ distinct solutions?

Comment: the question doesnt specify but yes im pretty sure

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Framing a question well is pretty tough, but you can learn how to do it. As a first step, perhaps you can confirm what exact question you're asking before any of us spend time trying to answer the wrong one. That's just basic politeness.

Comment: Have you worked out any specific examples, like $n = 6$ and $k = 2$ or $k = 3$? If so, why not show us your work (You can click "edit" under your question to add stuff), and give a little more detail on how you used "stars and bars", and why. That'll help us better understand what kinds of hints or answers might push you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You precise in a comment that the $a_i$ are non-negative integers.

In that case the number of solutions to the inequality corresponds to the number of  [weak compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%28combinatorics%29) of $m$
into exactly $k$ parts, with $0 \le m \le n$.

Now, the number of weak compositions of $m$ into $k$ parts is 
$$
\binom{m+k-1}{m}
$$
and the sum on $m$ gives
$$
\eqalign{
  & N(n) = \sum\limits_{m = 0}^n {\binom{m+k-1}{m}}  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,m\,\left( { \le \,n} \right)} {\binom{n-m}{n-m}\binom{m+k-1}{m}} 
 =  \binom{n+k}{n} \cr} 
$$

where:
 - the first step is to replace the summation bounds with the binomial $\binom{n-m}{n-m}$ that contains the upper bound implicitely,
while the lower bound is implicit in the original binomial;
 - the second step is to apply the "double convolution" , which in general reads
$$
\eqalign{
  & \sum\limits_{\left( { - m\, \le } \right)\,k\,\left( { \le \,n} \right)\,} 
 {\binom{r+k}{m+k} \binom{s-k}{n-k}}
  = \sum\limits_{\left( { - m\, \le } \right)\,k\,\left( { \le \,n} \right)\,} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{m + k} \binom{m-r-1}{m+k}
 \left( { - 1} \right)^{n - k} \binom{n-s-1}{n-k} }  =   \cr 
  &  = \left( { - 1} \right)^{m + n} \sum\limits_{\left( { - m\, \le } \right)\,k\,\left( { \le \,n} \right)\,} {\binom{m-r-1}{m+k} \binom{n-s-1}{n-k}}
  = \left( { - 1} \right)^{m + n} \binom{m+n-r-s-2}{m+n}  \cr 
  &  = \binom{r+s+1}{m+n}
\quad \left| \matrix{  \;r,s \in \mathbb C \hfill \cr   \,m,n \in \mathbb Z \hfill \cr}  \right. \cr} 
$$
applying the "upper negation" and the (standard) "convolution".

Comment: @G Cab could you elaborate on the double convolution formula and how you got the last two equations?

Comment: @Toylatte: I expanded the explanation of the passages: let me know if you still have doubts.